# How can I stretch a QLayout or QFrame, nested within a bigger layout?

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have this code set up to create a sidebar and I'm not entirely sure how to stretch it so that the left, top, and bottom sides touch the edge of the window.

```
QFrame *sidebar = new QFrame;
QLabel *sideItemA = new QLabel("Item A");
QLabel *sideItemB = new QLabel("Item B");
QVBoxLayout *sidebarLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
sidebarLayout->addWidget(sideItemA);
sidebarLayout->addWidget(sideItemB);
sidebarLayout->addStretch();
sidebar->setLayout(sidebarLayout);
sidebar->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
sidebar->setStyleSheet("background-color:#FFFFFF");
sidebar->setMinimumWidth(150);
mainLayout->addWidget(sidebar);
```

Here is a screenshot of what the above code looks like:
[image: screenshot]

I've tried doing this using nested layouts too and I get the same result. Any pointers? Is this even the best way to do it?

Comment: what parts do you want touching what?   I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to achieve

Comment: You could show an image of what you want to get to understand you better.

Comment: @xaxxon  I'd like like the sidebar to touch the top, bottom, and left edges of the window, basically a normal sidebar. I'll add an image with an example.

Comment: Can you set some sort of "padding" on mainLayout to be 0?   Then you could add something for the right hand side that does have some "padding" and then put the right-hand-side stuff inside that to maintain the padding around those parts?   (complete guess).  Also, please edit the additional details of what you'd like to see directly into your question instead of adding them as comments.

Comment: Looking a little more closely, maybe setting margins is what you want, instead of "padding" like I mentioned above:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins

Comment: @xaxxon Thanks! that actually got me closer to what I was trying to do but changes the padding of everything within the main layout (code not included above). I'll be damned if I have to add custom padding for every element thats not the sidebar

Comment: @eyllanesc added image!!

Comment: @xkenshin14x that's why you'd add a second container just for the right side stuff.

Comment: @xaxxon thanks daddy that worked perfectly

Comment: you're welcome :)  Good luck.